# Header section css for responsive web design to ipad,desktop,phone

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, angular-ui-bootstrap, responsive

Tried to find the solution for RWD to header section using boostrap but not working for ipad and phone.I want to show logo and menu and nav cart for responsive.How to achive to get the solution.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark mb-5">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" routerLink='/products'><img width="50" height="50" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcROSGhNugPi-wkkvEePwHNppt8AaZRlUk-y9yEapagLNUaXxy_G" class="logo mr-2" /></a>
  <div class="navbar-expand mr-auto">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink='/home'>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink='/service'>Service</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink='/about'>About</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink='/contact'>Contact</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink='/test1'>test1</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink='/test2'>test2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink='/test3'>test3</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink='/test4'>test4</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-expand ml-auto navbar-nav">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://github.com/beeman" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://twitter.com/beeman_nl" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://medium.com/@beeman" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-medium"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/tutorial-angular-cli-v6-styling-bootstrap-ywyjmv?file=src/app/ui/header/header.component.html

Comment: Can you also share the CSS you used ?

Comment: @MihaiT:: Please check my stackblitz

Comment: Why don't you share here the CSS in the stackoverflow code snippet ? It's easier to get an answer that way. Considering the fact that this has nothing to do with angular but just HTML and CSS and bootstrap

Comment: I have used @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";  So how can i share here?

Comment: Yes. You can make a code snippet ( like the one in your question ) and add external libraries with `link` not with @import . There's a button to the left.

Comment: @MihaiT:Edited my question

Comment: So you don't use any other CSS styles ? just the ones from bootstrap?

Comment: Yes..just the ones from bootstrap

Comment: so on responsive you don't want bootstrap to hide your `logo, menu`

Comment: Do not hide logo..i am expecting same like this..http://www.youboo.in/

Comment: Please check this  http://www.youboo.in/     for mobile,desktop,ipad

Comment: @NilaVaani, Try like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-bootstrap-navbar-ejtqnx

Comment: @ManirajMurugan:How to show right side logos for mobile,desktop,ipad

Comment: @NilaVaani, Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-bootstrap-navbar-mr4qxg